# Future payment api with the single payment api - Can I use consent within the paypal sdk?

Tags: ios, paypal

From this document: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md#create-a-payment

It says:

> Once a user has authorized your app to use their PayPal account, you can then use that authorization to obtain tokens that let you create future payments from that user.

Thats fine, however I see no mention of using the aforementioned token in a PayPal payment call using the native sdk?

Do we really need to do this via network requests (i.e. cUrl?)

Some clarification on this point would be great. As it seems a little weird that the PayPal payment api cannot accept a token from a future payment authorization in it's call.

An answer to this would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

@PersuitOfPerfection, usually it would be your server that would be handling the tasks of securely storing the refresh token and then -- when a payment is to occur -- using the refresh token to generate an access token and using the access token to create a payment.

After all, it will be your server that controls whatever action the payment is for -- providing a service or shipping physical goods.

Are you planning some different model of client/server/delivery interaction?

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for responding. The area I am most confused about is when a user consents to future payments, the documentation seems to imply that any single payments made in the app from there on out will not require the user to login. However from my testing this is not the case. The docs state to use the access token to allow this behaviour to happen, but do not say how one should pass the access token to the paypal payment object (from within the native iOS SDK). Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: Future payments and single payments are not interconnected in any way. Consenting to the former does not change the need to login for the latter. Let me know which section of the docs suggested otherwise to you, so we can try to make our documentation more clear.

Comment: Thanks dave. This document: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/ - says "When you integrate your mobile app with PayPal Mobile SDK 2.0, your customers can give permission to be billed multiple times in the future without logging into their PayPal account." To me that says that they consent to not having to log in again to pay for another item? If that is not the case then can you explain in layman's terms what the future payment system is actually used for? ( A use case explanation would be great ) thanks.

Comment: The use case already in the field is Uber. The user consents to future payments via PayPal. Subsequently, any time that the user obtains a ride from Uber, Uber's server sends a payment request to PayPal's server without user interaction. The only user interaction is between the user and the Uber mobile app, which in turn tells the Uber server to handle everything.

Comment: Right that makes more sense now. So this should be handled server side, exempt from the paypal sdk which hands off responsibility to the server once the user consents to the future payments.. correct? If you would be so kind as to link me to the documentation which describes how to set up the server side interaction (sending payment requests to paypal) i would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for all your help thus far.

Comment: @PersuitOfPerfection the document you linked to originally, [Future Payments Server-Side Integration](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md), is the relevant one.

Comment: Ok Dave. Thank you very much for all of your help! Appreciated. :)

Comment: @DaveGoldman please suggest me how uber get payment by user, means  when driver complete ride then uber server authorize of a payment and capture payment at a time?

Comment: @Nik's for information about how and when Uber processes payments, you would have to talk to someone at Uber.